# How to clear the settings and configurations for all Application Virtualization (App-V) applications

Tags: windows, app-v

How can I clear the cache of all settings and configurations for all of my Application Virtualization (App-V) applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [sftmime command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817090.aspx) to change and configure App-V packages, and applications.

To clear all settings and configurations for all of your App-V applications, run the [following command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc843647.aspx) from a command prompt:

```
sftmime clear obj:app
```

By default, `sftmime` is located in the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client
```

Answer (score 1):

The App-V repair command reverts an application's virtualized filesystem back to it's original state.

The [App-V Client UI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41186) provides access to the repair command:

[image]

Using Powershell you can achieve the same thing:

```
Repair-AppvClientPackage -Name 7-zip
```